# Spring boot Load properties from database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, properties

I have a requirement to load property code and description (an object will hold these values) from database. Currently I have these values being populated from properties file.
The values of these properties depend on the downstream system sending the response. I even have default values if I don't get a matching property from downstream.
What I have done so far:

1. Connect to Oracle db using hibernate to retrieve values from db.
2. Join two tables (one for default and another for system specific values) to get the data. Form list of objects from received data.
3. Compare data received from db with String variables I already have. Add property code and description if the variable name match with property name from db.

Though the code works as expected, this is not a clean solution. Can someone please suggest better approach for the same.

Comment: Could you please add some information about what you have done so far to solve your problem? Please check [ask] and [mcve] to understand what is a good question on [so]

Comment: in spring, you can use the propertysource system via annotation and simply supply your own: `PropertySourceFactory` this will be executed by spring, in there you can load whichever code you want and populate the properties accordingly